# I need to get the body of an incoming email in Gmail and write it on a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Okay, so I have been looking tutorials but everything I find about receiving emails with google apps is confusing for me. I would like to know how I can get the body of an incoming email and write it on a cell of a Spreadsheet. I know that you can get a Spreadsheet cell and use it as the body of a sending email, but I was wondering if I could do the opposite.

Thank you very much :D

Comment: Share your code, what have you tried it so far

Answer (score 0):

Just been doing some quick Googling about it and found this Github post:

https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708